# SQL to select the latest occurence based on three columns

Tags: sql

So let's say I have a table that looks something like this

| Name | Department | Login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Batman | A1 | 03-01-2022 |
| Spiderman | A1 | 03-04-2022 |
| Spiderman | B3 | 03-02-2022 |
| Superman | B3 | 03-08-2022 |
| Catwoman | A2 | 03-23-2022 |
| Venom | C2 | 03-25-2022 |
| Batman | A1 | 03-12-2022 |

Now, I would like to get the latest Login value for each unique name (in reality this is a unique ID but in this example I put names just for readability). The problem is that if a Name has logged in from two (or more) different departments, I get two results (or more) for that name, but I would only want the latest Login regardless of department ASWELL as the Name and the Department from where the last login took place.

I've tried multiple variations of queries and the closest I've gotten is this:¨

```
SELECT Name, Department, max(Login)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name, Department
```

Which won't work for Spiderman because he has logged in from both A1 and B3.

Any tips on how to accomplish what I want?

Actual output:

| Name | Department | Login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spiderman | A1 | 03-04-2022 |
| Spiderman | B3 | 03-02-2022 |
| Superman | B3 | 03-08-2022 |
| Catwoman | A2 | 03-23-2022 |
| Venom | C2 | 03-25-2022 |
| Batman | A1 | 03-12-2022 |

Expected output:

| Name | Department | Login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spiderman | A1 | 03-04-2022 |
| Superman | B3 | 03-08-2022 |
| Catwoman | A2 | 03-23-2022 |
| Venom | C2 | 03-25-2022 |
| Batman | A1 | 03-12-2022 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: If you extract name and department you always will get 2 results (in this case) so reconsider what you need. Doing the select on name and max(login) gives you unique result but with department will be always two.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much my problem. If I only needed the name it would be no big deal but I need to know aswell from what department their last login was and I can't seem to find any easy way around this

@jarlh Sorry about that, I updated the post with further clarification

Comment: But you have it! If you want only the last department just add ROWNUM < 2 or TOP 1 or something like this to your sentence. Up to your database

Comment: you can use analytic function for this ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Alright thanks guys, I think I will be able to get it now when I get into work tomorrow. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Department, Login
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Department, Login
        ,row_number() over (partition by Name, order by name, login desc) rn
    FROM [table]
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
select * from 
(SELECT Name, Department,login, 
row_number() over (partition by name order by login desc) rn
FROM table
)t
where t.rn = 1;
```